# How to choose a backboard for a garden basketball court?

Tags: equipment, basketball

My friend and I are building our own garden basketball court. We also want to make it into a small squash court. The problem we are having is wether we should buy a standalone basketball stand or a wall mounted one.

The garden is not too big so space is precious which is why we are leaning to the wall mounted one, its also easier to set up as mentioned [here](http://crookedcollectionpeaceworld.tumblr.com/post/138478030571/my-own-court). All they needed is a wall mounted board, some power tools, a telescopic ladder and some screwdrivers.

The problem with a standalone would be levelling. Our garden is not level so it would be harder to set up properly where as a wall mounted one only needs to be levelled to the wall, which is easy to do.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.